# How in vb.net can I insert a value on a read only property?

Tags: vb.net, rgb, readonly

I want to create a color using the property r,g,b but unfortunately Visual Studio says r is a readonly value. Please help.

```
Dim newcolor As Color
newcolor.R = vermelho
newcolor.G = verde
newcolor.B = azul
```

Comment: R, G, B should be 0-255 values. For more information, you can check out http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51797-colors-in-vbnet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the shared method [FromArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim red As Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)
```

Or in your case

```
Dim newcolor As Color = Color.FromArgb(vermelho, verde, azul)
```

Comment: Thx man it helped a lot, and sorry for my bad english. I realy appreciated all the help you guys gave.

Answer (score 0):

Well R, G and B are definitely read only as they only have a GET method. I normally work with colors like this:

```
Dim Color As System.Drawing.Color

Color = Color.LightSteelBlue
Color = Color.SteelBlue
```

You can also do:

```
Dim ColorCode As Integer
ColorCode = Color.SteelBlue.ToArgb
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't if this is the `System.Drawing.Color` struct.

If you look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Color) for `Color.R`, you will see there is not a backing field for you to set. Unless of course you manipulate the `Value`, but then you may as well just declare a new Color each time you need to update it.

```
public byte R 
{
    get 
    {
        return(byte)((Value >> ARGBRedShift) & 0xFF);
    }
}
```